# Convert .csv into .json using python

Tags: json, python-3.x, mongodb, csv

I am trying to convert csv into json file using python3. I keep getting this error, FileNotFound, when the csv file exists in the directory. Please help me fix the issue. Below is the code i tried. Also i would be grateful, if anyone could suggest how to transfer MongoDB database into a json file using python3.

```py
import csv, json, os

#get all csv files from the directory
dir_path = r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\output_files'
inputfile = [file for file in os.listdir(dir_path) if file.endswith('.csv')]
print(inputfile)
for file in inputfile:
    with open(file, "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            id = row['ID']
            data[id] = row
```

Writing the files out using this code...

```py
with open(outputfile, "a") as jsonfile:
    jsonfile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Produces the following:

```py
['adult_diapers.csv', 'groceries.csv', 'health_supplements.csv', 'mobility_aids.csv']
```

Here's my error in more detail:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-1aac06308031> in <module>
      6 print(inputfile)
      7 for file in inputfile:
----> 8     with open(file, "r") as csvfile:
      9         reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     10         for row in reader:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'adult_diapers.csv'
```

Comment: Is the full path specified? Looks like it's just the filename and not the full path to the file. Add `dir_path`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to coorect by mentioning os.join(dir_path)

Answer (score 1):

Is the full path specified? Looks like it's just the filename and not the full path to the file. Add `dir_path` and use `os.path.join()` to concatenate the path and the filename as follows:

```
with open(os.path.join(dir_path, file), "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

And your final code becomes:

```
import csv, json, os

#get all csv files from the directory
dir_path = r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\output_files'
inputfile = [file for file in os.listdir(dir_path) if file.endswith('.csv')]
print(inputfile)
for file in inputfile:
    with open(os.path.join(dir_path, file), "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            id = row['ID']
            data[id] = row

    with open(outputfile, "a") as jsonfile:
        jsonfile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```